# download torrents with aria2c

Tags: bittorrent

I have installed aria2 in my Ubuntu. But I am not sure of how to download the torrents with aria2c. I am very new to Ubuntu.

Thank you.

Comment: /home/iball/Pictures/Screenshot from 2013-12-08 14:24:22.png

Answer (score 5):

you did not mention the command you are using , any way Here an example for you.

```
aria2c http://site/file.torrent
```

If you want deal with Magnet link

```
aria2c --follow-torrent=mem http://site/file.torrent
```

[If you want to know more about area2c torrent, click](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/aria2/wiki/UsageExample#BitTorrent%20Download)

Comment: ok i have a torrent in the home folder already so i used it like that aria2c [kickass.to]insidious.chapter.2.2013.720p.bluray.x264.sparks.publichd.torrent....it shows unsupported format ...i'll put screenshot here see and tell what am i doing wroong ?? can u tell me how to put screenshots here so i can show wats happning

Comment: Copy and paste your terminal log and paste it here with ubuntu.pastebin.com

Comment: iball@iball:~$ aria2c http://torcache.net/torrent/6C3B9298E4D9348F93ED893CB70FA2845F550D71.torrent?title=[kickass.to]the.outsider.2013.dvdrip.xvid.juggs.etrg
    [#63e633 0B/0B CN:1 DL:0B]                                                                      
    12/08 20:01:55 [NOTICE] File already exists. Renamed to /home/iball/[kickass.to]the.outsider.2013.dvdrip.xvid.juggs.etrg.torrent.2.

Comment: 12/08 20:01:56 [NOTICE] Download complete: /home/iball/[kickass.to]the.outsider.2013.dvdrip.xvid.juggs.etrg.torrent.2
 
Download Results:
gid   |stat|avg speed  |path/URI
======+====+===========+=======================================================
63e633|OK  |    85KiB/s|/home/iball/[kickass.to]the.outsider.2013.dvdrip.xvid.juggs.etrg.torrent.2
 
Status Legend:
(OK):download completed......my prob is that it download the torrent file bt not the torrent .somehow i was able to download direct link with area2c bt i wasnt able to get this to work ur suggestred cmd for magnet also worked

Comment: You want to download the torrent or the file from the download torrent.

Comment: the file from the torrent ...spoose i have a movie torrent ...i want to download the whole movie ..